# Algorithm for a complex graph visit

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a graph of this type
[image]

And I have to estimate the probability to end in a node of a given color (let's say red for example). This probability is given by the chance of ending in a node of that color and not ending in any other node of that color in the graph. For example the probability of ending in the upper red node is 0.5*(1-(0.4*0.8)), which is the product of the chance of ending directly in the upper red node (0.5) and the chance of not ending in the lower red node (1- 0.4 *0.8).
So the total probability of ending in a red node is 0.5 *(1-(0.4 *0.8)) + 0.4 *0.8 *(1-0.5).

How can I formulate an algorithm solving this problem?

I created an algorithm that didn't care about the chance of not ending in any node of the same color in the tree (so its total probability of ending in a red node simply was 0.5 + 0.4 *0.8) that I could share if it's useful, but I'm having trouble in this algorithm

The simplier code I was talking before is this one:

```
 def algorithm(self, startingNode, nodeToFind):
    valueToReturn = 0
    nodesToVisit = startingNode.nodesConnected
    for j in nodesToVisit:
        if j == nodeToFind:
            probabilityToVisit = graph.search_edge(startingNode,j)
            valueToReturn += probabilityToVisit
        else:
            valueToReturn += self.algorithm(j,nodeToFind)
    return valueToReturn
```

The graph is a sort of tree where each node has a number of leaves <=2, and no successors of node X can have the same color of node X. Although two red nodes have almost all the same properties, they differ in their leaves because each single red node will have different sons based on the path traversed to reach it

Comment: Please share your code. Do you know of dynamic programming?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark this is a problem I have to solve for the project of my dynamic programming exam. For the code, I'm trying to make it easier to look at and I'll add it to the description

Comment: Got it. If you haven't read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) yet, you probably should (in particular, the point about school policy). If you aren't allowed to get outside assistance on this problem, you should delete this question.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I've read it and I'm allowed to use any outside information I can find, this one is a small algorithm problem in a big project I have to do. By the way I added a code that is similar to the one I'm currently using but easier to read

Comment: Your analysis of the example seems not correct. You should also take into account that there is a probability that one moves from the upper red node on to the blue one on its right, which would mean we didn't **end** in a red node. In my opinion this should appear in the formula.

Comment: @trincot I didn't express myself correctly, once the red node is reached, you have to count it no matter of what happens after that node in the path. For how I built my graph I am 100% sure that no other red node will occur after one in the same path (after reaching the one in the upper part of the graph, there will be no other red node in the graph after the first red node)

Comment: OK, I understand. Can the same node be reached via *different* paths? Is the graph an acyclic graph? Is it a tree?

Comment: @trincot it is a sort of tree where each node has a number of leaves <=2 and no successor of a node X can have the same color of node X. The probability of reaching a red node in a certain path is given by the prob of reaching it following directly that path multiplied by the probability of NOT reaching a red node following any other path

Comment: Can a node have two *incoming* edges?

Comment: @trincot For simplicity I'd say no, but all the different red nodes in facts are simply the same node. So what I want to achieve is the chance of reaching the red node following any path, but with the property explained above where the probability of reaching red node in a certain path is given by the prob of reaching it following directly that path multiplied by the probability of NOT reaching red node following any other path. I hope I explained myself properly

Comment: It is confusing to say the red ones are the same node, because that would mean you could continue from the bottom red node to the top blue node. Are you sure you want it to be like that?

Comment: @trincot unfortunately I can't modify the graph since it's the representation of a real world problem where each node X represents a product and the sons of X represent the suggested products once you buy product X

Comment: I am not saying you need to modify it. I just want to understand what the possibilities are at the **single** red node you speak of. Can one go from that single node to the **single** blue node? How does it work?

Comment: I think it is actually like this: a node is a *state*. And although the color red denotes one specific thing, the color does not fully describe the state. The state also includes the *path* that has been traversed, and that implies what the "next" possibilities are to extend that path. And so the top red node is *not* the same as the bottom red node. They are about the same "red", but they do not represent the same state, and so we should see them as distinct nodes. Can you confirm it is like that?

Comment: @trincot yes exactly, the reason I separate them is the one you said, every node knows the path used to reach it and has different edges based on that

Comment: I still don't get your calculations. If I am in the white node, I have 0.5 probability to go up, 0.4 to go down, and 0.1 (remaining) to stay where I am. The change I go to the upper red node is therefore 0.5. I don't understand why you bring in more into that calculation, as if I could still -- within that probability of 0.5 -- go *down*. But this is not true, or how does this work? Once I go up, it is sure I am not going down, right? Or not?

Comment: @trincot no, you could take both the paths simultaneously, so once you go up, you are not sure you can't go down

Comment: Then I will pass on this question. I don't understand that concept.